# JS minification, Heroku and jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: jquery, angularjs, heroku

I just dig into an error on my web app.
It's running with Rails 3 and AngularJS and when the web app deployed on Heroku, I had this error :

```
Unknown provider: tProvider <- t
```

I found some ways on Stackoverflow about minification issues and then go deeper to point out the line(s).
Then after tests I found it and was surprised :

```
 $scope.list = jQuery.parseJSON(list_json);
```

`list_json`is datas stocked temporarly in div. This works well on local.
Any idea why `jQuery.parseJSON` is creating this error ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: btw I know that Angular/jQuery is not a good combination ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using minified JS on your local, that would explain the discrepancy. If you look a little bit at how minification works, you'll see that your Dependencies are turned into variable names like `a` and `b` to make them "mini-er". So Angular doesn't know what you're referring to anymore. There are a few ways to handle this:

1. [ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) is a tool that can automate this for you and avoid repetition.
2. When you're defining factories, controllers, services, etc., you can use array notation with explicit variable naming to prevent your var names from getting minified. An example is below.

**BAD**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyController', function ($scope, OtherDep) {

    });
```

**GOOD**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'OtherDep', function ($scope, OtherDep) {

    }]);
```

*NOTE: when you're using array notation, make sure that your 'quoted' vars are in the same order as your (injected, vars).*

Comment: but if I don't use this notation but something like a simple `function MyCtrl($scope,$filter) {}`, it shouldn't be affected by this. I'm I wrong ?

Comment: I just added the ngmin-rails gem on the app but I still get same error

Comment: If you're using the approach of defining a controller as a function, then you'll need to follow that with `MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];` See the docs in the official angular tutorial: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#controller_a-note-on-minification Essentially this solves the same problem identified in the answer above: when something is minified, the variable name changes, and Angular can't identify it when it is injected in other cases.